# Creating an infinite dictionary. It's possible?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to define a function that receive infinite values in dictonary, but the the exit is taking only the characters of the last 2 key and value.

Any suggestion?

```
def infinityInvent():
    infinityInvent = []
    while True:
        keys = input(f'Enter a item (or blank to stop): ')
        values = input(f'What the value? ')
        if keys == '':
            break
        infinityInvent = dict(zip(keys, values)) # or infinityInvent = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}

infinityInvent()
```

Comment: What do you mean "infinite values", that is impossible.

Comment: I mean that dictionary can receive how many values i want/wish, and, the result is a dictionary with this values. Of course that result is a finite dictionary with finite values, i just put this name cause to be more practical =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an item in the dict, not redefine the dict:

```
def infinityInvent():
    infinityInvent = {}
    while True:
        key = input(f'Enter a item (or blank to stop): ')
        if key == '':
            break
        value = input(f'What the value? ')
        infinityInvent[key] = value
    return infinityInvent
    
print(infinityInvent())
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't work. The way you are putting the code seems to me not accepting values ​​of type string. See error message: "infinityInvent[key] = int(value)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Could you help me?